# NETFLIX not working because of components Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, netflix

I'm using Ubuntu 14.

Netflix isn't working with Chrome.

it says:

```
cannot find all components. check WidevineCdm and upgrade it.
```

But there is no upgrade to do in Chrome components.

[image: Plug In Screen]

[image: Component Screen]

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the component.

Go to the "address"   `chrome://components`

Find `WidevineCdm` in the list and make sure it is enabled

You may also need to check `chrome://plugins` and make sure it is enabled there as well.

EDIT:

Under `chrome://components` click the `check the update` button.   Restart and try again

Comment: it's already enabled

Comment: Make sure to check for updates to the component.  See edit

Comment: WidevineCdm it's not in there..

Comment: Are you using Chromium or Chrome?  Is the logo blue or normal?

Comment: Another question, how is it "already enabled" if "it's not in there?"

Comment: i've posted what i see

Comment: i'm sorry are two links because i'm still not allowed to charge it directly

Comment: Are you using chrome or chromium? Is it the open source version?

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using?  Can you screen shot the "ABOUT" screen

Comment: solution! http://askubuntu.com/questions/724879/chrome-on-ubuntu-no-longer-supports-netflix-latest-update-removed-widevine-comp?rq=1